# Can't use existing asset poses

Tags: pose-mode

I made some poses and could use them but I can't anymore and I have no clue what causes this. When I apply a pose, my model does not use it, it stays in T-pose. I must have activated some kind of freeze option somehow.

Any idea?

[image]

You can download the file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t35goWrIoiNAVEJXz8dJ-_pUno89nF2O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is the armature in *[Pose Position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/properties/skeleton.html)* mode? If it's in the *Rest Position* nothing happens.

Comment: @Blunder yes it's in pose position. I can modify the pose by hand, I just can't apply asset poses that I registered before.

Comment: Looks like your poses are empty for some reason. The related actions have no keyframes. For each pose, Blender creates an action and adds keyframes for the selected bones. You can inspect them in the *Action Editor*. I've just tried to create a new pose with no bones selected (which would result in no keyframes) but this is rejected with an error in the status bar. Creating a new pose with selected bones works without any problems. Hard to tell what happened. Have you accidentally deleted the keyframes?